# Python сборка приложения с помощью py2app

Tags: python-3.x, macos, pygame

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь собрать свое приложение с помощью `py2app`. Создал и написал свой `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']
DATA_FILES = ['images/ship.png', 'images/ufo.png', 'fonts/a_lcdnova.ttf']
APP_NAME = "Alien Invasion"

OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'includes': ('pygame'),
    'iconfile': 'images/ship.icns'
}
setup(
    name=APP_NAME,
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

`main.py`:

```
from Button import Button
from Enemy import Enemy
from Ship import Ship
from random import randint
import pygame
import sys


def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1920, 1080), pygame.FULLSCREEN)

    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    while True:
        # некоторые действия с использованием импортированных классов

        pygame.display.flip()


run_game()
```

При запуске `python3 setup.py py2app` получаю следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понимаю, `Done!` означает, что все хорошо. Но при запуске `Alien Invasion.app` получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На клавиши не реагирует, срабатывает только нажатие на клавишу Ввод (закрывает окно).

Comment: минимальный пример с проблемой бы :)

Comment: @gil9red добавил в ответ конкретику!

Comment: 1) попробуйте из консоли запустить (мб приложение в консоль ругается) либо собрать с поддержкой консоли 2) добавить в код логирования 3) еще можно глобальные логгеры включить: `import logging logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)`, мб pygame что-то напишет или один из библиотечных модулей

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо @gil9red за наводку. Если запустить приложение через консоль, то оно выдаст ошибку, что не может найти все ресурсы. Следует складывать все ресурсы сразу в папку с `main.py`, не во вложенные папки, тогда все будет хорошо.
Либо указывать *папки* в качестве ресурсов
Вот так работает правильно:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['main.py']
DATA_FILES = ['images', 'fonts']
APP_NAME = "Alien Invasion"

OPTIONS = {
    'argv_emulation': True,
    'includes': ('pygame', 'random', 'sys'),
    'iconfile': 'images/ship.icns'
}
setup(
    name=APP_NAME,
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```